# Field upgrades not working

Tags: battlefield-4

Field upgrades do not seem to work, even though the upgrade is highlighted in the bar:

[image: Field Upgrades]

I normally notice with the engineer because I do not get the extra mines, however I guess it is probably happening with all classes and upgrade options.

Is this a bug or do I need to do something to enable the first upgrade?

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes specifically with that perk as well.

Comment: They only work after you've respawned since they unlocked. Did you die in the meantime and they still didn't work?

Comment: @Sentry: That's correct. They do appear eventually, but it seems to be after a random period of sticking with the same class for a while.

Comment: I've also noticed this - and sometimes I get the 6 mines and I can place 3. When I place the 4th the first one dissapears i.e. I can carry 6 but only deploy 3 at a time.

Comment: @tombull89 The first perk in the Anti-tank engineer field upgrade is 3 extra mines (6 total) _carried_. The third perk in the same field upgrade is _placing_ up to 6 mines. [Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-4/Anti-Tank) (site formatting might look awful, sorry in advance)

Comment: @turbo what. I thought that was a bug. I suppose I didn't read the description of the unlock tree properly. Thanks for pointing that out.